# Can we know the definition of the function in GDB?

Tags: gdb, pthreads

I am learning gdb to make life little easier. I searched Google for this but couldn't find the answer. Though I learned that `$1` is a gdb variable that can be used later anywhere in the debugging. But for my question there is no info.

Code:

```
if (pthread_create (&mythread[i], NULL, (void *)threadFunction,(void *) i))
{
   printf ("\nerror creating thread");
   exit (1);
}
```

**My question is - can I see the definition of threadFunction or pthread_create function assuming gdb knows it.**

Comment: Please explain precisely why do you need to look into the implementation of `pthread_create`, which is a standard function? So **edit your question** to improve it!

Comment: to know the signature so that I can compare what is passed. Also, like what is happening inside with the parameters. Otherwise, we can always read source code of these functions outside gdb. Just wondered, whether it's possible to do it there and then only.

Comment: The signature of `pthread_create` is in the documentation and in `<pthread.h>` standard header. BTW, how many dozen of years of work can you afford to understand all the details (and your brain is probably too small to keep all of them).

Comment: BTW `\n` should appear at end -not start- of `printf` control format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB uses debug information, often in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format, which contains names -e.g. of local variables-, source locations (source path, line number), etc.... That debug information exists for code compiled with `-g` (passed to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler). So you can get source location information for every code compiled with `-g` (and you could recompile yourself with `-g` the libraries you are using). Most of the time that DWARF info sits in the same shared library or object file (in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format) but there is some way to keep it in a separate file.

`pthread_create` is a C standard library POSIX function  (it is using [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) such as [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html); see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for an exhaustive list). Read carefully the [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) documentation. On Linux most [C standard libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (notably GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study their source code. You may need to find a debug variant of your libc, e.g. some `libc-dbg` Debian package.

> can I see the definition of `threadFunction`

You can use the [`list` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/List.html) of GDB. So try `list threadFunction` (assuming that the source code containing its definition was compiled with `-g`).

> ... or of `pthread_create`

The definition of `pthread_create` (provided by your C standard library) would appear only if you use a libc compiled with debug info. It may be faster to browse its source code (e.g. [`src/thread/pthread_create.c`](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/thread/pthread_create.c) of 
[musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)) than to recompile your entire `libc` with debug info.

To understand the behavior of `pthread_create` you may want to understand  [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), but it is better to trust the documentation in [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html). Most of it (of `clone`) is implemented *inside* the Linux kernel, which is also free software (downloadable on [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/)). You could spend many years in understanding all the details (but ask also on [kernelnewbies.org](https://kernelnewbies.org/) after having begin to study some kernel code).

Many Linux distributions are mostly made of free software, totalizing more than ten billions lines of source code. You surely need more than a lifetime to study most of them. [Abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering)) is practically essential in software development (so choose what details you are willing to forget). Read also about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and about [leaky abstractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction).

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (a bit old) and [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). Both are freely downloadable. https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ is a good tutorial on Posix Threads Programming.

Comment: Hi, I meant a command in gdb to see the definition of the function there only.

Eg: 

`info break` - enlists all the breakpoints
`p x` - prints value of x 

similarly, is there any command we can use to know the definition of the function? something like `def function`

Comment: You can `break pthread_create` with GDB (and you don't need `libc-dbg` for that)

Comment: Hi thanks, list <function_name> , but can't we do that with C Standard library POSIX function?

Comment: You'll better read carefully the specification of `pthread_create` than study its source code.